# AngularJS editable grid using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've created an editable grid using `ng-repeat`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/86/

The edited data can be saved using the Save button or the changes discarded using the Cancel button. However, the Cancel button requires 2 clicks to reset the row, and I can't figure out why. The first click resets the data, the second replaces the textboxes with the labels. The Cancel button works fine if a new row is added, though.

Why does the Cancel button require 2 clicks to reset on existing rows? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit edit on a row you're setting `entry.editMode = true`, storing an index of edited field inside `$scope.editing` and copying current record into `$scope.newField`.

Note that at this point **`$scope.newField === true`** and **`$scope.editing !== false`**.

Then when you hit cancel for the first time you set `entry.editMode = false` and then inside `cancel` function inside the `if` statement 
**`$scope.appkeys[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField`** which overrides element in array that is a source for `ng-repeat`. At this point the edited entry `editMode === true` as mentioned above. However the `$scope.editing === false`.

A second hit on cancel again sets `entry.editMode = false`, but this time `$scope.editing === false` and the `if` statement inside `cancel` function will not execute and will not override `entry` element.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Thw8n/88/) in one of many possible ways.